# Terraform detach and re-attach ebs volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am using Terraform to spin up EC2's. After EC2 is created, I write some data to /myapp. How do I detach /myapp and re-attach it every time when EC2 gets destroyed and recreated again? I did some research and found following code may be the option:

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_ec2" {
  ami           = "${var.ami_id}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
  count         = "${var.node_count}"
  subnet_id     = "${var.subnet_id}"
  key_name      = "${var.key_pair}"

  root_block_device = {
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = 20
    delete_on_termination = false
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_ids}"]
}


resource "aws_ebs_volume" "my_vol" {
  size              = 120
  count             = "${var.node_count}"
  type              = "gp2"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "my_vol_att" {
  device_name = "/dev/xvdf"
  volume_id   = "${element(aws_ebs_volume.my_vol.*.id, count.index)}"
  instance_id = "${element(aws_instance.my_ec2.*.id, count.index)}"
  count       = "${var.node_count}"
}
```

My questions are:

If my_ec2 get destroyed:

1. ec2 is gone
2. my_vol is gone?
3. my_vol_att stays? If so, where can I see it?

When I run above Terraform code again to re-create ec2 after it gets destroyed:

1. will it create new my_vol id?
2. what will happen to
3. my_vol_att?

What exactly is my_vol_att? A pointer or a copy of m_vol that is attached to device and never gets destroyed unless manually delete it?

Sorry, my questions might sound silly as I am very new to both Terraform and AWS.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by destroy.  Are you going to destroy the entire TF plan using the TF command?  Are you going to use the TF command to destroy the individual my_ec2 resource?  Are you going to otherwise destroy my_ec2 in some other way such as the AWS console or CLI?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens when the user_data changes. For example you want to say install jenkins on an ebs volume which is persistent

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "jenkins-data" {
  availability_zone = local.jenkins-az-location
  size = 20
  type = "gp2"
  tags = {
    Name = "jenkins-data"
  }
}


resource "aws_volume_attachment" "jenkins-data-attachment" {
  device_name = var.INSTANCE_DEVICE_NAME
  volume_id = aws_ebs_volume.jenkins-data.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.jenkins-instance.id
  skip_destroy = true
}
```

then your user_data

```
#!/bin/bash

# volume setup
vgchange -ay

DEVICE_FS=`blkid -o value -s TYPE ${DEVICE}`
if [ "`echo -n $DEVICE_FS`" == "" ] ; then
  # wait for the device to be attached
  DEVICENAME=`echo "${DEVICE}" | awk -F '/' '{print $3}'`
  DEVICEEXISTS=''
  while [[ -z $DEVICEEXISTS ]]; do
    echo "checking $DEVICENAME"
    DEVICEEXISTS=`lsblk |grep "$DEVICENAME" |wc -l`
    if [[ $DEVICEEXISTS != "1" ]]; then
      sleep 15
    fi
  done
  pvcreate ${DEVICE}
  vgcreate data ${DEVICE}
  lvcreate --name volume1 -l 100%FREE data
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/data/volume1
fi
mkdir -p /var/lib/jenkins
echo '/dev/data/volume1 /var/lib/jenkins ext4 defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
mount /var/lib/jenkins
```

now down the track you want to change the user data for whatever reason and you run terraform again and it will destroy the instance and build another instance and your drive along with it.

To be honest I never looked into this I just take a snapshot of the volume every time I need to do some invasive surgery and it the volume gets destroyed I re-create it from the snapshot then push the changes back into the terraform state file, can be a pain but generally in my case Jenkins is not completely blown away often.

Once I get a change to look into this more I'll probably update this but at the moment I'm sure there is a option in TF to not destroy assets via api or something.

Answer (score 1):

If I capture the sentiment of your questions correctly, you would like to be able to destroy the EC2 instance *independently* of the EBS volume.

This is possible, but requires some dynamic resolution via `data` resources.

What I would do here is create a Terraform module that encapsulates the code you have written above, but replaces the `aws_ebs_volume` resource with a data source like so:

### my_module/main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_ec2" {
  ami           = "${var.ami_id}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
  count         = "${var.node_count}"
  subnet_id     = "${var.subnet_id}"
  key_name      = "${var.key_pair}"

  root_block_device = {
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = 20
    delete_on_termination = false
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_ids}"]
}


data "aws_ebs_volume" "my_vol" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "volume-type"
    values = ["gp2"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.volume_name]
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "my_vol_att" {
  device_name = "/dev/xvdf"
  volume_id   = "${element(aws_ebs_volume.my_vol.*.id, count.index)}"
  instance_id = "${element(aws_instance.my_ec2.*.id, count.index)}"
  count       = "${var.node_count}"
}

variable "volume_name"{
  type = string
  default = "my_volume"
}
```

### main.tf

```
module {
  source = "./my-module"
  volume_name = "MyManuallyCreatedVolume
}
```

Note: That the data source I use here is trying to match a volume via the `Name` tag, which you didn't set in your code but is set in the example [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ebs_volume).

Architecting your code like this will allow you to create the volume manually, or via some higher level terraform code that calls this one. As long as your state files are separate, you will be able to destroy your Instance(s) and volumes independently of one-another.